# How to access images of amazon s3 bucket by making request of https url in safari

Tags: amazon-s3, https, safari, cross-domain

I have one site that uses HTTPS protocol and my images are load from amazon s3 bucket. my fabric js canvas uses that images. when I load the image into the canvas using https request. at that time it will throw an error of cross-origin.
I am using fabric js version 1.7.22
I use the Safari browser.

I try to setup cors configuration like Below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

but this is not working in safari browser.

Please Help me. how to allow images of Amazon s3 to load in my canvas?

Comment: *"I have one site that uses HTTPS protocol"* then why does your CORS configuration not include `https://example.com`?  http != https

Comment: Sorry, it's my writing mistake, actually, I set https in URL. and I also try * instead of static URL but it also not working.